# Angular application fs.readFileSync alternative

Tags: node.js, angular, fs

I am using angular localize-router and I want my JSON translations to load from a remote file.

When I launch my 'ng serve' the browser console says: 'fs.readFileSync is not a function.'

My code is:

```
export class TranslateUniversalLoader implements TranslateLoader {
/**
 * Gets the translations from the server
 * @param lang
 * @returns {any}
 */
public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next(
            //Perfom API call here
            fs.readFileSync(`http://example.com/locales/${lang}.json`, 'utf8')
        );
        observer.complete();

    });
  }
}
```

I've read that it's impossible to run 'fs' in a browser. If so, how can I replace this with some kind of synchronous API call? If I perform an asynchronous call, the translations won't be loaded.

Or should I do something else to make 'fs' working?

Comment: *"I've read that it's impossible to run 'fs' in a browser.."* - And you probably needed to keep reading and understand why code running in a **browser** that can open files is highly **insecure**. It's not just `fs`, but the whole concept of code opening a file.

Comment: *"I want my JSON translations to load from a remote file."* - That's what HTTP is for - it reads remote files. I'm not sure how `fs` fits into the picture here? Try `request`/`request-promise`.

Comment: Thank you for these comments guys, this was in the example of the git repo, so that's why I 'chose' it, but I'll try "request/promise" again

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) get a file like this `fetch(http://example.com/locales/${lang}.json)` instead.